# How do I make an IgnoreProperty convention in fluent nhibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, conventions

```
public class MyObjectMap : IAutoMappingOverride<MyObject>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<MyObject> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.InterfaceProperty);
    }
}
```

I am currently doing this in every map... how can I make this into a convention? I am adding conventions like so:

```
    private Action<IConventionFinder> GetConventions()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Add<ForeignKeyConvention>();
            c.Add<HasManyConvention>();
            c.Add<HasManyToManyConvention>();
            c.Add<ManyToManyTableNameConvention>();
            c.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>();
            c.Add<ReferenceConvention>();
            c.Add<TableNameConvention>();
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not something related to Convention,however it is subject to Mapping Overriding, try this:

```
public class AutoMapDefaultConfig : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(FluentNHibernate.Member member)
    {
        if (member.Name == "InterfaceProperty")
            return false;
        return base.ShouldMap(member);

    }
}
```

i haven't try this actually, but I think it may help,and notice that the **DefaultAutomappingConfiguration** is in Fluent-NHibernate  V1.1